# getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute... immediately inside while loop, but not before

Tags: python, nonetype

I've discovered node becomes NoneType just after `while True:` but not one line before. I can't figure out why, or what to do about it. `render()` does not change the node object, and I know the loop fails on the first `render()` call.

```py
def _select(self, node):
    "Find an unexplored descendent of `node`"
    path = []
    "Make the tree one layer better. (Train for one iteration.)"
    path = self._select(node)
    leaf = path[-1]

    "Update the `children` dict with the children of `node`"
    if node not in self.children:
        self.children[node] = node.find_children()

    "Returns the reward for a random simulation (to completion) of `node`"
    invert_reward = True
    node.render()

    while True:
        node.render()
        if node.is_terminal():
            reward = node.reward()
            break
        node = node.find_random_child()
        invert_reward = not invert_reward
    reward = 1-reward if invert_reward else reward

    "Send the reward back up to the ancestors of the leaf"
    for node in reversed(path):
        self.N[node] += 1
        self.Q[node] += reward
        reward = 1 - reward  # 1 for me is 0 for my enemy, and vice
```

I expect both calls to `node.render()` to visualize the node object, but the second one gives:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't happen in a later iteration, after `node.find_random_child()` has returned `None`?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I'm sure, because render() would print something each time the loop runs. I've recently put ```sys.stdout.flush()``` right after render(), but same thing.

Comment: Apart from advising you to step through the code with `pdb` and simply see what happens, it's hard to help with incomplete code. Can you reduce this to a minimal _complete_ example that reproduces the problem?